# Trying to compress avi to mp4 with ffmpeg - files are corrupted

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4
```

This is the command I am using. Video is unplayable. Doing h264 without conversion to mp4 also doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the original video is currupeted at some part and thus causing failure on convertion.

Comment: First check out if the inputfile is not corrupted; otherwise , give a try for this :`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset faster -tune fastdecode output.mp4`

Comment: Input file plays normally. (It's uncompressed avi exported from TrackMania)

Comment: Does the encoder report any errors? Does it take a reasonable amount of time to compress the video? Does the resulting file have a realistic size? What are you trying to play the video with? What exactly happens?

Comment: Share full log of `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -t 2 -y output.mp4`

Comment: I forgot about this thread, seems like I don't have this issue now; I have different one, however. Find it in my profile's questions